# XMLViewresolver gives a 404: Not found exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resolver

I'm trying to get familiar with the XMLViewResolver, so I included the following into m *-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/spring-views.xml</value>
    </property> 
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
```

The Spring-views.xml looks like this (just a snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="insertEntryForm" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
    <property name="url" value="/WEB-INF/views/admin/insertEntryForm.jsp"></property>
</bean>
....
```

When I try to load this jsp it gives me the following error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/LiteratureVisualization/admin/insertEntryForm.html"
```

How can I solve this problem?
I want to use XMLViewResolver, because I can map multiple folders (inside the views-directory) individually... or is there a different solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `web.xml` configuration file in your project, check that XML file is included in context parameters:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-pdf-views.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I had the same problem integrating iText library and I had to include XML file here.